# Unresolved inclusion error in Bada

Tags: c++, std, bada

I'm developing and app for Bada OS and i need use vectors and other standar structures from stl.
But when i write:

```
#include <vector>
```

The Bada sdk throws me an error:

```
unresolved inclusion: vector
```

I'm looking for a solution on Internet and the solution always is include the stl's path on the configuration of the project (Bada IDE are derivated from Eclipse).

But i don't know where is that path, i tried to include all the path that i found (in minGW, bada directory, etc) and the compiler doesn't run if i include it.

Please help me! (sorry about my poor english)

Comment: I am using wave, which has OS bada. I couldn't resist myself to comment here **bada sucks full time!!!** . They might even will stop supporting it and go with `Tizen` OS as rumors says.

Comment: When i finish my app u don't think that ;)

Comment: This is your first app development for bada or you had developed some already in past for bada? lemme know I'll try them

Comment: bada has it share of issues, but unlike Tizen it allows for porting C(++) code from iOS/Android/WinMobile. Tizen, AFAIK, only allows HTML apps from third parties. So I'm rooting for bada to stay. Word of caution: stay away from in-app purchases on bada. They never work.

Answer (score 0):

`<vector>` is part of the C++ standard library. If you can get to other headers from the standard library, then you don't need to mess with the path.

Some embedded compilers might not do templates, so `<vector>` wouldn't be part of their library. If that's the case, you're out of luck.

Comment: No, i'm not able to get some file of the standar library.
Bada allowed the stl library (excepts some structures).
I think that the problem is about Eclipse, not Bada.

Comment: "some embedded compilers don't do templates" - that's so idiotic that no such compiler can be called "sane".

Comment: @Griwes - Japanese compiler writers pushed this about ten years ago, when the perception was that templates inherently led to code bloat. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_C%2B%2B.

Comment: @Adrian - sounds like you've got a problem with the compiler installation. Sorry, I can't help there.

Comment: @PeteBecker, fine, but, as you noted, t'was "ten years ago" - currently no such compiler can be called "sane". But that's only my opinion ;)

Answer (score 0):

If the compiler throwing you the error, or Eclipse? In my bada experience, standard C++ headers (STL and such) are marked by Eclipse as unresolved, but the compiler finds them all right.

This is not a compilation error - this is an IDE error. Ignore it and continue working. STL is supported on bada.

Bada SDK 2.0.5, targeting bada 2.0 (both HVGA and WVGA).

Answer (score 0):

even if it says this, it compiles fine, Eclipse gives me the same remark when including  to use the c++ string, but it compiles fine

Best regards